# Php function returns with no value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this table (wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta):

[image: proof that it has value inside it]

And this table (wp_woocommerce_order_items):

[image: proof #2]

I'm using a function (functions.php) which returns these item id's in an array:

```
function retrieve_orders_ids_from_a_product_id( $product_id, $order_date ) {
global $wpdb;

$table_posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$table_items = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_items";
$table_itemmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_itemmeta";

// Define HERE the orders status to include in  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==
$orders_statuses = "'wc-processing'";

# Requesting All defined statuses Orders IDs for a defined product ID
$orders_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT DISTINCT $table_items.order_id
    FROM $table_itemmeta, $table_items, $table_posts
    WHERE  $table_items.order_item_id = $table_itemmeta.order_item_id
    AND $table_items.order_id = $table_posts.ID
    AND $table_posts.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
    AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
    AND $table_itemmeta.meta_value LIKE '$product_id'
    AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE 'order_date'
    AND $table_itemmeta.meta_value LIKE '$order_date'
    ORDER BY $table_items.order_item_id DESC"
);
// return an array of Orders IDs for the given product ID
return $orders_ids;
}
```

And I call it inside my page:

```
<?php $orders_ids_array = retrieve_orders_ids_from_a_product_id($getid, $order_date); ?>
```

I'm 100% sure that `$getid` (`$getid` = `product_id`) and `$order_date` has the exact value which I from my db.

But if I `print_r` the array it returns with:

> Array ( )

instead of any value.

Finally I need to count these id-s, but if doesn't return anything it looks impossible to me.

Comment: Can you run your sql statement inside phpmyadmin or Sequel Pro or something? To troubleshoot it.

Comment: Tried. It runs but the return is nothing.

Comment: Okay, without the order_date it works and gives back the id's. And I think I know what was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```
 AND $table_itemmeta.meta_value LIKE 'order_date'
```

should be

```
 AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE 'order_date'
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, but still didn't gives me back any value

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it has 2 problems. First:

```
 AND $table_itemmeta.meta_value LIKE 'order_date'
```

should be

```
 AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE 'order_date'
```

and the second is the `$order_date` is always refreshed because my `foreach()` loop.